# Copy Paste works only if Range is greater then 20 rows

Tags: excel, vba

Would you know what is the following code adjustment needed. Range I have set up (A1:B20) changes over time. The first block of data stays be between A1:B20 and the second block of data always will be between A25:B60. Ranges will change over time. First block of data could reach 200 rows going down. After my code reaches the second block of data and my range falls between that block of data it picks up the range only if I have adjusted manually the range. Please note, Second block of data normally provides duplicates from the first block.

How could I have my code automatically select the first block of data past my range output without having to adjust the "range" manually?

```
Sub CopyPaste()

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim Sheet2 As Worksheet
Dim Results As Worksheet
Dim LookupLastrow As Long


    'code line will set values from sheet 
     ("Sheet1") into ("Sheet2") starting 5 rows down.

         Set Results = Sheets("Sheet2")
         lastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End  (xlUp).row


               Range("A1:B20" & lastRowcount).Copy
               Results.Range("A" & lastRow + 5).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

          Application.GoTo ActiveSheet.Range("A1"), True
          Application.CutCopyMode = False


 End Sub
```

Comment: `lastRowcount` is not declared.  I think you meant to use `lastRow`, however it should be after `B`.  The way you are using it, if there are 40 rows, the result will be 2040.

Comment: Like Darren said, change  Range("A1:B20" & lastRowcount).Copy to  Range("A1:B" & lastRow).Copy

Comment: `Option Explicit` will protect you from typos like this

Comment: @mooseman, code was updated to Range("A1:B" & lastRow).Copy, I get partial data, not the entire row column data. Why is that??

Comment: When you find `lastRow` you are using `Sheet2`, then copying from `Sheet1` (although you do not qualify the sheet in your command, suggest you change).  That will give you a different set of data.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the picture you showed, the following code will capture the entire top and bottom sections, regardless of how many lines or columns exists.  This assumes your top section will start in "A8" as shown.  You can edit the code to reflect your actual sheet names.

```
Sub CopyPaste()

    Dim OrigLastRow As Long
    Dim OrigLastCol As Long

    Dim DestLastRow As Long

    Dim OrigRng As Range

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet

    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Origin")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Destination")

    OrigLastRow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    OrigLastCol = ws1.Cells(10, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    DestLastRow = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 5

    Set OrigRng = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(8, 1), ws1.Cells(OrigLastRow, OrigLastCol))

    OrigRng.Copy
    ws2.Cells(DestLastRow, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

    Application.CutCopyMode = False


End Sub
```

The version below creates a top and bottom section like your picture and copies both sections separately with a 5 row gap in the destination.

```
Sub CopyPaste2()

    Dim OrigLastRow As Long
    Dim OrigLastCol As Long
    Dim TopLastRow As Long
    Dim BotLastRow As Long

    Dim DestLastRow As Long

    Dim OrigTopRng As Range
    Dim OrigBotRng As Range

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet

    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Origin")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Destination")

    'Assumes contiguous data from row 8 down
    TopLastRow = ws1.Cells(8, 1).End(xlDown).Row
    BotLastRow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    OrigLastCol = ws1.Cells(10, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    DestLastRow = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 5

    'Assumes we are starting the top range in row 8
    Set OrigTopRng = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(8, 1), ws1.Cells(TopLastRow, OrigLastCol))

    'Columns I & J as shown in the picture
    Set OrigBotRng = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(TopLastRow + 5, 9), ws1.Cells(BotLastRow, 10))

    OrigTopRng.Copy
    ws2.Cells(DestLastRow, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

    'Recalculate destination last row
    DestLastRow = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 5

    OrigBotRng.Copy
    ws2.Cells(DestLastRow, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False


End Sub
```

Comment: After I ran your code update, all data is captured and set unevenly through all columns unsorted. [code:] works incorrectly.

Comment: Code displays, "run time error"  subscript out of range

Comment: Changed Sheets TAB "Names" with different Sheet numbers, after I ran, data copy pasted into ROW A34 no other data was set on any other cells.

Comment: This code assumes that you are using `Sheet1` and `Sheet2` as noted in your original post.  If the origin worksheet is not `Sheet1`, then replace the name.  Same with the destination.  `Subscript out of range` means it doesn't exist.  I can only go from what you told me.  You may post a pic of both sheets if you want precise explanation, otherwise it is standard copy/paste.

Comment: let me explain what is going on with your code. Your code copies columns with rows, however, if my range equals (A9:N20) and I have columns "B, C" empty, your code will paste on Sheet2 my data source starting with Column "D" from Sheet1, not from Column("A9").  I would like to include an image of the flat file, however, I di not have access to insert images for you to look at!

Comment: I have tried fixing your code to see hwy Column "A" is not transferring over to Sheet2, no success. Please update your code I believe it not "Dynamical" with data source.

Comment: I'm not sure you are understanding "dynamic" ranges.  `(Rows.Count, Column Number).End(xlUp).Row` will determine the total number of rows used (as long as you select the right column).  There are other methods, but you get the same result.  You also need to understand how this site works.  You don't edit my posts to fit your understanding.  You can comment in the comments section.  Your edits did not correct the situation.  You still had the wrong syntax for adding the `lastrowcount` to the range.

Answer (score 0):

Think simple. No need to build strings for range addresses, and no need for using the clipboard with `.Copy` and `.Paste`. **Use a direct assignment to the `.Value` property in a table of cells.**

```
Public Sub CopyValues()

    Dim r_src As Range, r_dst As Range
    ' Source starts at row 20
    Set r_src = Sheets("Sheet 2").Cells(20, 1)
    ' Destination starts at row 5
    Set r_dst = Sheets("Sheet 1").Cells(5, 1)

    Dim n As Long
    ' Count the non-empty cells
    n = r_src.Range(r_src, r_src.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

    ' Copy n rows and 2 columns with one command
    r_dst.Resize(n, 2).Value = r_src.Resize(n, 2).Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Would you be able to update your code to "Dynamically" look for the updates cells going down the row, then paste continual past row 20  from Sheet1 source into destination Sheet2?  Please share more details on your code, or, update code. At this time your code counts and copies over into sheet2, however, my data source file changes with data output, so, your code remains static, cells could reach 200 rows.

Comment: Why would I want to do that? Just copy all the values over and it will ensure the worksheets contain the same values. The operation is super fast anyway. Please be specific on how counting the non-empty cells in "Sheet 2" isn't enough? How is the number of cells to be copied determined?

Comment: Due to the reason that my output file changes, you operation is very basic and limited because your code does not roll down automatically to select all cells. 
Example: Set r_src = Sheets("Sheet 2").Cells(20, 1)  I still remain to understand how would I be able to include the same file with code that will include 200 rows?

Comment: @hmm4089 - Actually the `.Resize()` statement selects all the cells specified. For example to select a 20×5 table starting from `"B2"` you just type `Range("B2").Resize(20,5)`. This is equivalent to `Range("B2:F22")`

Comment: I tried the additional following and it appears to work. My example to select a region from left to right on the table starting from Sheet1 "B2" going into Sheet2 "A2".    Would this code be better? Please reply, let me know if your familiar with "region" selection code?

EXAMPLE:  
' Place value from ("A1") in ("B1")
    Range("B2" & lastRowcount).CurrentRegion.Copy
    Sheet2.Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues